# Has anthropogenic climate change been disproven?

Tags: climate-change, weather, meteorology

Some scientists attribute non-terrestrial causes for climate change. Are they correct?

For example, this scientist attributes current weather extremes to solar activity, moon orbit cycles and magnetic connections with astronomical bodies. Can mainstream scientists show they have a better answer? If so, what is it?

Here is the video that explains the evidence that opposes anthropogenic CO2 warming.
http://youtu.be/6R26PXRrgds

Comment: @Articuno I do agree this is a duplicate, just phrased from a less neutral perspective.